# Navigation drawer text parallel

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

How to make the children text align parallel to "Operator"?

[image]

I want something like this

[image]

Here my code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          _createHeader(context),
          ExpansionTile(
            childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            title: Text("operator".tr()),
            leading: const Icon(Icons.person), //add icon
            children: [
              ListTile(
                title: Text("dashboard".tr()),
                onTap: () {
                  //action on press
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("properties".tr()),
                onTap: () {
                  //action on press
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpansionTile is basically a ListTile that expands to reveal its children. In your example, since the children are ListTile\s, we are looking at an expansion of what is already the parent widget. So you do to the children, what you have done to the ExpansionTile.

The ListTile widget is separated into three main row sections which are the `leading`, `title x subtitle` and `trailing` widgets. Each of these sections is evenly spaced by the *tilePadding* parameter which [defaults](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile/tilePadding.html) to `EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0)`.

The leading widget is [nullable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile/leading.html), hence if you do not explicitly define a widget for leading, it will not occupy any space. So to make your children ListTile\s align with the ExpansionTile, you need to explicitly define a widget for leading just as you have done with `leading: const Icon(Icons.person)`. However, because you most likely don't want to actually display a widget there, we can safely do `leading: const SizedBox()` and we have our solution

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          _createHeader(context),
          ExpansionTile(
            childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            expandedCrossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            title: Text("operator".tr()),
            leading: const Icon(Icons.person), //add icon
            children: [
              ListTile(
                leading: const SizedBox(),
                title: Text("dashboard".tr()),
                onTap: () {
                  //action on press
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const SizedBox(),
                title: Text("properties".tr()),
                onTap: () {
                  //action on press
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Padding widget for spacing

```
Padding(
 padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
 child: [CHILD_WIDGET],
)
```